# Fetch snap SPARQL query using OWL API in java web

Tags: java, sparql, owl, protege

oke, I have this snap SPARQL query using protege

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX :<http://www.semanticweb.org/astrid/ontologies/2019/5/mpasiv2#>

SELECT ?resep_makanan
WHERE {
    ?resep_makanan rdf:type :resep_makanan.
    ?resep_makanan :resep_untuk :6-7_bulan.
}
ORDER BY ?resep_makanan
```

and it works, i get instance for my `resep_makanan` which are food name, with object property `resep_untuk` (recipe_for) baby who is 6-7_bulan (6-7_month old).
then in my java web code, i write

```
PREFIX :<http://www.semanticweb.org/astrid/ontologies/2019/5/mpasiv2#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?resep_makanan
WHERE {
Type (?resep_makanan, :resep_makanan),
PropertyValue(?resep_makanan, :resep_untuk, :6-7_bulan)
}
order by ?resep_makanan
```

But i get 0 query result. 
Im using OWL API.
How should i write it correctly?

Comment: OWL API is definitely **not** the API that you're using to handle SPARQL queries. What is it? SPARQL-DL? IT would be also interesting to see which versions you use as well as the code to run the queries.

Comment: and what is "javaweb"?

Comment: sorry, i mean java web. im using OWL API right now

Comment: show the JAVA code and which APIs exactly  you use. There is also no need to open another thread for the same question ...

Comment: and one more time, what is "java web"? this is not a standard term or at least I don't know what this describes.

Comment: Hi, you're new to StackOverflow so it might help to mention two things: use tags for all the relevant parts of your question (for example, you said you use OWL API but there is no owl-api tag on your question; adding tags is more likely to capture the attention of knowledgeable people), and when you have code that does not behave as you expect show the code and the data. You've put the data and the expectations in your question but not the code you're running, so people cannot tell whether there's an error in your code. this would also clarify which APIs you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up 'snap SPARQL' brings the `https://github.com/protegeproject/snap-sparql-query` project, which I believe is what you're actually using to run your queries (as it's used in Protege).

If that's the case, you're not using OWL API for the SPARQL part of your code, as OWL API does not support SPARQL itself; I don't know the snap sparql project but, as it integrates with Protege, which is OWL API based, I assume OWL API is used for interfacing a SPARQL based API with Protege. From the project dependencies, I think that's `de-derivo-sparqldlapi`.

To answer your question, if the same query does not produce a result outside of Protege this must depend on it not being sent to the same SPARQL endpoint or to a different set up of the endpoint (e.g., does your query depend on reasoning for its results?)

**Some** of this information might be in the code that you're running and have not shown here, but we won't be able to tell without seeing it.

Comment: she is indeed using SPARQL-DL API, but this does not support full SPARQL: https://www.derivo.de/en/resources/sparql-dl-api/sparql-dl-syntax/ - in her other questions she's trying to use filter expressions as well, thus, this won't work here. If she really needs OWL API - and we don't know what she's doing at all - then [Ont API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki) is the way to go when using SPARQL with OWL API.

Comment: Snap SPARQL plugin is just using Sesame(RDF4J) as SPARQL backend combined with the reasoning capabilities of the OWL reasoners from OWL API.

Comment: Yes, i think i mixed up everything. OWL API is indeed SPARQL DL API. But in my project i need to use snap sparql because imy ontolgy has some SWRL rule for reasoning. Thank you, i will read more into it before asking again. Thank you